# SQL Outer Join Time Series with Data in Different Times

Tags: mysql

I was trying to combine multiple Cash Flows table for multiple projects into one table using SQL. The query i was using is listed below,

```
SELECT  a.DATE1, b.DATE2, a.CF1, b.CF2
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b 
ON b.DATE2= a.DATE1
```

and the result table is listed below,

[image]

Since cash flows are taken place in different date for different project, some of them might happen in same day, some might not. I am wondering how can I adjust my code so that the result will looks like this,

[image]

Where we combine first 2 date columns. Keep the date value if the other one is NULL, and remove duplicated values if cash flows happened on the same day.

Since there are multiple projects I will need to combine, the method should be robust for expansion.

I have tried to use following,

```
SELECT  ISNULL(a.DATE1, '') + ISNULL(b.DATE2, ''), a.CF1, b.CF2
FROM ...
```

However, this only solves the NULL part, and will actually add up duplicated date, and result in a new date.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `COALESCE(a.Date1,b.Date2)` can help

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN` AFAIK, so I'm wondering how you actually generated the first table.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Mgmt Studio, so probably this is not same as MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This using coalesce().

```
        SELECT  coalesce(a.DATE1, b.DATE2)as date, a.CF1, b.CF2
        FROM a
        FULL OUTER JOIN b 
        ON b.DATE2= a.DATE1
```

Comment: This function is awesome! Thanks!

Comment: In addition, I am pretty new to SQL and I am wondering how can I find functions like COALESCE when I need them? Is there a place where I can go and search for all functions like this, or do I have to post question here?

Comment: you can easily find these by reading some SQL ebooks or textbooks also you can refer online tutorials like http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ or www.tutorialspoint.com/sql

Comment: Thanks for the hint!